# Is it possible to check, if a function was called?

Tags: java, file, outputstream

I have an `ArrayList` of objects, which I need to sort using two attributes (using Comparators). I need to save the sorted output to a text file with a different name, depending on the attribute used to sort. For example, if the list is sorted by `attribute1` then file will be `attribute1.txt`, if `attribute2` the file will be `attribute2.txt`.

How I want it to work (pseudocode):

```
if(sortedByAtr1){
    FileWriter fwstream = new FileWriter(sortedByAtribute1.getName()+".txt");   
}
else(sortedByAtr2){
    FileWriter fwstream = new FileWriter(sortedByAtribute2.getName()+".txt");
}
```

Is this possible?
I appreciate any advice.
Thanks.

Servo

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  You'll have to define FileWriter fwstream outside of the if statement, so you can use it in the code following the if.

Comment: Can you provide us with more context, like how is the sorting being done, that you can't just set a variable when you sort with `attribute1` or `attribute2`? Like `isAttribute1 = false` would mean it was `attribute2` that was called. Or a string.. We need more information.

Comment: Its to much lines. 
But @Gilbert Le Blanc have a good point,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an object-oriented approach to solving this requirement.

Use a wrapper for the List and its sorting attribute:

```
public class ListSorter<V> {

    private final List<V> values;
    private String sortingAttribute;

    public ListSorter(List<V> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public void sort(AttributeComparator<V> comparator) {
        Collections.sort(values, comparator);
        sortingAttribute = comparator.getSortingAttribute();
    }

    public String getSortingAttribute() {
        return sortingAttribute;
    }
}
```

Extend the Comparator interface so you can get your attribute name:

```
public interface AttributeComparator<T> extends Comparator<T> {
    public String getSortingAttribute();
}
```

Create custom AttributeComparators like this:

```
public class FooBarComparator implements AttributeComparator<Foo> {

    public int compare(Foo foo1, Foo foo2) {
        // skipped nullchecks for brevity
        return foo1.getBar().compare(foo2.getBar());
    }

    public String getSortingAttribute() {
        return "bar";
    }
```

}

Use:

```
List<Foo> yourList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
ListSorter<Foo> example = new ListSorter<Foo>(yourList);
AttributeComparator comparator1 = new FooBarComparator();
example.sort(comparator1);
FileWriter fwstream = new FileWriter(example.getSortingAttribute() +".txt");
```